# Override Bundle Controller Symfony2

Tags: symfony, overriding, bundle

I'm using EasyAdminBundle in my Symfony2 application.

I want to override some actions of the controller, and I follow the [Bundle instructions](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/6-customizing-new-edit-actions.md).

But The application never enter in my actions, always enter in the bundle action.

This is my route:

```
easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
```

And in my bundle, I have a AdminController class which extends EasyAdminController

```
...
class AdminController extends EasyAdminController
/**
 * @Route("/admin/", name="admin")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return parent::indexAction($request);
}

protected function listAction() {
//Never enter here    
...
}
```

Anybody know how can I override this action in my controller?

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I've the same problem.

Comment: Yes, in my routing, I set route for my controller overrided with annotation, and in that controller, the differents actions with annotations.